# How to completely remove unused kernel packages in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel

The question at hand is:

How to completely remove (purge) unused (removed via GUI) kernel packages in Linux Mint 18.x after man removes these kernels via Mint Update Manager -> Linux Kernels window?

As you can see below, there is only one kernel installed, I have removed all others:

[image: Mint Update Manager -> Linux Kernels]

Since they were removed, I presumed they were purged completely, but I was wrong. Once I did:

```
dpkg --list | grep "linux-image"
```

There was more like 30 packages with *rc* prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *rc* prefix - these two letters signify the status of the packages as follows:

1. *r* : the package was marked for removal
2. *c* : the configuration files are present in the system

---

First we need to get the list of the packages, that were removed, while leaving the configuration behind:

```
dpkg --list | grep "^rc  linux-image" | cut --delimiter " " --fields 3
```

---

Once we have the list, we can manually purge these kernel packages, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.10.0-20-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-20-generic
```

Notice, we are actually always removing two packages:

1. linux-image-*
2. linux-image-extra-*

---

One problem you will possibly encounter is a warning that the kernel library directory wasn't removed because it's not empty. I decided that I will leave it as it is, because I would have to google another hour for an explanation whether or not I can just:

```
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic/
```